# Invalid syntax querying JSON LOAD on Python

Tags: python, json, api, pandas, python-requests

I'm trying to print out the data from the sig API but it is giving me an error although the url is correct.

```
import requests
import json
from json import loads
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

requests.get("https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?zip=eh1+1af&offset=0&city=Edinburgh&format=json&lon=-3.19000005722&category_id=34&photo-host=public&page=500&radius=25.0&fields=&lat=55.9500007629&order=id&desc=false&sig_id=243750775&sig=9072b77fb34f5b84a392da2505fd946c58e94fe5")
```

The error is here, apparently ("Invalid syntax");

```
print json.load(requests.get("https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?zip=eh1+1af&offset=0&city=Edinburgh&format=json&lon=-3.19000005722&category_id=34&photo-host=public&page=500&radius=25.0&fields=&lat=55.9500007629&order=id&desc=false&sig_id=243750775&sig=9072b77fb34f5b84a392da2505fd946c58e94fe5"))
```

Thank you

Comment: No, you should be doing `requests.get(url).json()`

Comment: Thanks I've done that and it's returned ; <bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>> How can I see my data in order to put it into a dataframe?

Comment: Err, note the braces `()`.

Comment: of course. Will not forget them :)

Comment: You would not get <bound method> if you added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `requests`, you should be aware that the `Response` object has a `json` method you can call to retrieve JSON from the HTTP response.

```
r = requests.get(url).json()

type(r)
dict
```

You can load the JSON response `r` into a dataframe, if you have to.

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(r['results'])
```

Comment: Would the alternative be to retrieve it as a csv file like in BeautifulSoup or can that not be acquired with JSON? Also, what exactly does the type(r) dict do?

Comment: @Sahra bs4 is a webscraper, and it's meant to work with DOM trees, not JSON. `type(r)` is just showing you the result is loaded, nothing more. Feel free to ignore.

Comment: My baaaad! I literally typed out "type(r) dict" all as code... whereas type(r) is my input and dict is my output... please ignore this hiccup also! thanks again

Comment: @snow_fall Yes, sorry. That's my habit, don't mind it.

Comment: @coldspeed   Don't be sorry. That's good practice! I need to take it up too. You really helped me :))